# Calculation of the socle of $R$ for given algebra $R$

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, socle

I am thinking of calculation $Soc(R)$ for given algebra $R$.
But the definition of socle is too abstract to calculate.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socle_(mathematics)

Does anyone tell me how to calculate socle algorithmically？
For instance, what is the $soc(R)$ of following algebras $R$？

(1) $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^3,xy^2,y^4)$

(2) $R=\mathbb{C}\langle x,y \rangle /(x^2+1,y^2-1,xy+yx)$ (noncommutative algebra)

Comment: One trick I always use is that the Jacobson radical annihilates the socle, so you can sometimes narrow it down a bit by computing the Jacobson radical and its annihilator.  Note that in (2) you're talking about *two* socles, one on the left and one on the right.

Comment: I think i'm computing correctly that the first one is 6 dimensional, and its not semisimple, so the socle could be at most a direct sum of 5 simple submodules.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do you find (1)R is not semisimple？

Comment: Both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero nilpotent elements.

Comment: Actually that makes it easy to find the radical: it's the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$, so the ring is local.